# to give a responsive background pattern image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a pattern image in left side of a site which will behave its height respectively to the height of the div in the right side for responsive.

If I don't give height or put height in auto in class `side-pattern` then the background image doesn't display. I know that giving height doesn't make it responsive. I have tried giving `max-height` then also it doesn't display image. Also tried giving `position:absolute` to `side-pattern` div, it just interchange div from left tot right and another problem was, it doesn't help to display pattern image. Height and width of pattern.png is 75px 75px respectively.

My html and css that I have used is

```
 <div class="sj-main-container">
     <div class="col-lg-2 side-pattern margin-none">

     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-10 margin-none">
        <div class="sj-main-content">

         </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I have use bootstrap class to give a column.
CSS:

```
 .side-pattern {
background: url('img/pattern.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
height: 2082px;
 }

.sj-main-content {
 position: relative;
display: block;
overflow: visible;
}
```

[image: pattern image]

[image: site should be look like this]

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet, pattern image included, that reproduce the issue, so we have with what to work

Comment: @LGSon  OK i have included the pattern image want to display it without giving height

Comment: is this what you are after? https://plnkr.co/edit/gM2amcTOWa9Abc91imS2?p=preview

Comment: @Spluf  height of side-pattern div should be equal to the height of a sj-main-content div.

Comment: @Spluf Thats what i made by giving a fixed height but it doesn't behave responsively with the device. I just want to take height auto or respectively to the div of right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, from what I know CSS can't do that by it's own, but, you can do it with a bit of js like this:

HTML:

```
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 margin-none">
        <div class="sj-main-content">
            <p>
              Bacon ipsum dolor amet turducken jowl tenderloin sausage pork belly jerky ham pork chop short ribs ground round salami brisket pork loin chuck. Hamburger ham tenderloin, frankfurter ground round landjaeger beef ribs. Meatball turkey tail landjaeger ribeye brisket. Meatball cow filet mignon picanha pork belly ribeye ball tip alcatra ground round pork chop boudin rump spare ribs ham.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .side-pattern {
background-image: url("http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/weather.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
position:relative;
height:0px;
 }

.sj-main-content {
 position: relative;
display: block;
overflow: visible;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkMediaSize();
    $(window).resize(checkMediaSize);
})

function checkMediaSize() {
  var height = $(".sj-main-content").height();
  $(".side-pattern").css('height', height);
};
```

and [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gM2amcTOWa9Abc91imS2?p=preview) is a working example:

Comment: It worked but you need to give `position:absolute` to `.side-pattern` class. Thank you mate.